# PromiseKit: resolve method requires String and Void be equivalent

Tags: swift, types, swift5, promisekit

I'm trying to use PromiseKit v6 in iOS Swift 5 app but I trip on a very basic issue. The code below throws a compiler error:

```
let p1 = Promise<String> { seal in
   seal.resolve("Foo"); /// Referencing instance method 'resolve' on 'Resolver' 
                        /// requires the types 'String' and 'Void' be equivalent
}
```

I suspect this is something utterly stupid but what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check https://mxcl.dev/PromiseKit/news/2018/02/PromiseKit-6.0-Released/
where the changes are described:

> Promise.init We altered the main initializer:
>
> Promise { fulfill, reject in
>
> //… }
>   You now have:
>
> Promise { seal in
>       // seal.fulfill(foo)
>       // seal.reject(error)
>       // seal.resolve(foo, error) }

so `seal.fulfill("Foo")` will work in your case